# How to retrieve the highest peak length of y-coordinates and their respective x-coordinates to a separate file using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

**Input File**

```
3000121 2
3000151 5
3000181 8
3000211 5
3000241 7
3000271 4
3000301 1
3000331 4
3000361 6
3000391 10
3000421 11
3000451 9
3000481 4
3000511 7
3000541 10
3000571 7
3000601 4
3000631 3
3000661 1
```

1st field represents the x-coordinates, 2nd field represents the y-coordinates.

**output file should be like this**

```
3000181 8
3000241 7
3000421 11
3000541 10
```

Comment: Why you choose this set of coordinates for output?

Comment: these are the coordinates which are having highest peak length in the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the previous records and compare them. If you find a `y` coordinate which is bigger than the previous one and bigger than the next one, then you have found a peak and can print it.

Try the following:

```
$ awk '{x=$1;y=$2;if(y<py&&py>ppy){print px,py}ppy=py;py=y;px=x}' file
3000181 8
3000241 7
3000421 11
3000541 10
```

Comment: can u say wat z py and ppy here, plz?

Comment: `py` refers to the "previous value of y" and `ppy` is the previous-previous value of y i.e. the one before `py`.

Answer (score 1):

File a.awk:

```
{
   if ( ( NR - 1 ) in x && ( NR - 2 ) in x ) 
   {   
       if ( y[NR - 1] > y[NR - 2] && y[NR - 1] > $2 )
       {   
           printf "%d %d\n", x[NR -1], y[NR - 1]            
       }   
   }   

   x[NR] = $1
   y[NR] = $2
}
```

Run:

```
awk -f a.awk input_file
```